# JSSOR Uncaught Error: prototype of 'thumbnavigator' not defined

Tags: jssor

I used jssor for image slide show in that if user clicked play show first time it works properly but if user clicking the play button again to initiate player even it is already loaded with another group of images. It shows this error `Uncaught Error: prototype of 'thumbnavigator' not defined.`[image: Here in this image you can see the error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jssor Slider cannot initialize the same "slider container" twice.

Please remove it and repopulate html code and then initialize it again.

```
$("#slider1_container").remove();
//do something to repopulate the "slider1_container" element.
...
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```