# JSSOR conflict with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jssor

I was testing Jssor and was a success.
When I edit the code to get the slides content from another file with Ajax it stop working.

But if instead I add them in the code without Ajax it work again.
There is a way to load the images dinamically?

Ajax function:

```
function getImages(n, type){
$.ajax({
    url: "./r/"+type+"/"+n+"/img",
    success: function(data){
        $("#slcont").html(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Problem loading page. Try later.");
    }
});
}
```

Import file content:

```
<div>
                <img u="image" src2="./i/works/web/1/w1_0.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src2="./i/works/web/1/w1_1.jpg" />
            </div>
```

Any Idea?

I tried also to call GetImages() from different places, included

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        getImages(i,t);
        var options = {
```

Note: **#slcont** is an ID assigned to: `<div u="slides" ...>`
I would avoid to post the full code, it will be long and anyway it is the same of the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conflicts with ajax call.
You can initialize jssor slider when the ajax call returns.

```
var jssor_slider1;
function getImages(n, type){
$.ajax({
    url: "./r/"+type+"/"+n+"/img",
    success: function(data){
        //you can optionally pause the slider if it exists already.
        if(jssor_slider1)
            jssor_slider1.$Pause();

        //empty slider1_container and repopulate html code in slider1_container again, and then reinitialize jssor slider.
        $("#slcont").html(data);
        ...
        jssor_slider1= new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container" ...;
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Problem loading page. Try later.");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Ok, that worked to get the data the first time, but if I change the content (the set of slides) ajax will load them but the initializaation seem not working.
Do I need to reload the page each time? or there is an option to re-initialize? No error this time on Javascript Console.

Comment: No need to reload page every time. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Didn't work, I saw [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357001/jssor-uncaught-error-prototype-of-thumbnavigator-not-defined) that I need to remove all slider1_content before repopulate it. I did it and seem working, but the div display still set to **none**, but if I change it manually to **block** it works